# Unable to view or write to shared Windows Drive

Tags: mount, ubuntu-core

I have mounted a Windows drive using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,user=james //share/company/IT/sales /mnt/winshareh/
```

The user has full admin permissions and can read write etc on the drive itself.

If I try to restore a database using SQL management studio, I can read the backup files in the mounted folder.
[image: Backup files showing in mounted folder]

However, if I cd to /mnt/winshareh on the terminal and list everything, I cannot see anything, it just gives me a blank result, or as below, I can create a file or folder (only as root, gives permission denied without sudo), and it will then list them, but *not* the backups that are actually inside the folder on the drive.

[image]

I have tried to add in rw to the mount command to see if this allows me to write to the folder with no difference.
I have also tried to unmount and remount this as a different user with still not difference.
I have also tried to give full permissions in the windows folder and I can confirm that I am able to create folders and files directly using Windows Explorer.

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount as local user: add your UID and GID in the mount options (say your local ID is 1000): `-o rw,user=james,uid=1000,gid=1000` so that you have proper access.
2. Have you been IN `/mnt/winshareh` during the mount? Then you are still seeing the old inonde before you mounted. Reenter the directory: `cd .` to update your current working directory.